# Rails scope - how to join 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 tables:

```
schools{id, name, desc, adress}
reviews{id, content, rating, school_id, user_id} # user_id & schoold_id is foregin keys
users{id, name, city}
```

How do I write a rails scope the joins all 3 tables and grab the column
the `schools.name` , `reviews.content` and `reviews.rating`, the `users.name`

I am using rails 3.2

Comment: If you've defined your associations (has_many, belongs_to) properly, you should be able to read the review and say review.school.name, review.user.name.

Comment: yeah I know that, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Review.joins(:school, :user).select("content, rating, name").all

Returns an array with objects with just these attributes.

Not sure yet how to handle school and users having the same attribute_name (name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :mashup, joins(:school, :user).select("content, rating, schools.name as sname, users.name as uname")
```

You can learn more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope)

Comment: updated my answer. Turns out you didn't need the .all at the end